Filtering MongoDB collection by date with .find() method ommits some of the records
I am trying to .filter() my MongoDB collection by date and $gte and $lte operators with the MongoDB node package. It simply doesn't work as expected and it omits some records. I have spent several hours Googling and trying to figure out why it is happening, but I have no idea anymore.
Here on the screenshot you see the full list of my records. I am trying to filter by the dateinvoice field. E.g. greater than 29.04.2024. It should return 7 records, but with the code below it ommits invoice number 00174-2024, which is seen on the second screenshot.

This is my code:
const df = req.query.dateFrom;
const query = {};
query['dateinvoice'] = { $gte: new Date(df).toISOString() };

const count = await db
  .collection('invoices')
  .find(query)
  .sort({_id: -1})
  .toArray();

The querying does happen, but the result omits some records which should be there, but are not.

It is missing at least 1 record, seen here in MongoDB Atlas collection browser:

I have tried different queries such as query['dateinvoice'] = { $gte: new Date(df) }; and query['dateinvoice'] = { $gte: df }, but every variation gives me different and wrong result.
What am I doing wrong here?

MongoDB query operators are type-sensitive, check the data type of the field in the database to make sure there aren't some date and some ISO string.

@Joe the MongoDB field is date type... Still not sure what I am doing wrong

.toISOString()

@user20042973 if you have checked my code, I am using the .toISOString() function!!

He was pointing out that .toISOString() returns a string, not a date, so if you get any responses when using .toISOString() in the query, you have at least one document in the database with a date in that field.

If your dataset is not extremely large, try an aggregation with a group stage like {"$group":{"_id":{"$type":"$dateinvoice"},"count":{"$sum":1}}}

Apologies to @user20042973 if "he" isn't the appropriate pronoun.

@Joe damn you are right, appreciated!
